# Can I deploy a contract from within a contract?

Tags: smart-contract, c++

We can create accounts from contract code:
https://github.com/angelol/smart_account_creator
and we can query things about accounts:
https://github.com/nsjames/Account-Has-Code

is there a way to deploy a contract to a newly created account from within a contract action?

Comment: I'd suggest seeing if deploying contracts from another contract is within best practices, what use case would you have for deploying another contract from another? Chances are a better solution would be to have a contract made which everyone can share, similar to `eosio.token` where people can make thousands of tokens all based off one contract.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWilliamson! That makes a lot of sense.